# error in updating mysql table with filters

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql table with the follwoing fields :

```
id, desc, value, people, amount, weight
```

in the above order i run the follwoing

```
update match1 set weight = 5 where desc = 'fat' and id != '6';
```

follwoing is the error message i get :

```
**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that** 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'desc = 'bat' and id = 6' at line 1
```

can someone please let me know whats wrong with this?

Comment: u sure that u run the same query, in the error is 'desc = 'bat' and id = 6' and in the code is desc = 'fat' and id != '6' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the column `desc` is a keyword in mysql. use backquotes i.e.

```
where `desc` = 'fat'
```

Comment: well i have a doubt:  1. when i ran update match1 set weight = 5 where id = 4; it gave no error even id is a keyword.

Comment: I must agree with Andrian - in this particular case `DESC` is really causing issues because it is a keyword in MySQL... Anyhow, backquoting columns in query statements is good practice, which keeps your statements more clean and gives you less chance of an error.

Comment: thanks laimoncijus will start doing that from now on. thanks adrian smith for your answer.